# Is there a hidden field deprecation feature for Managed packages?

Tags: managed-package, metadata-api

As an ISV we dream of deprecated fields for quite a while. While skimming through a custom objects meta.xml i just stumbled over a deprecated = false in a field definition

```
<fields>
    <fullName>idx_Record__c</fullName>
    <deprecated>false</deprecated>
    <description>My Field</description>
    <displayFormat>UST-{0}</displayFormat>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>MyField</label>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    <type>AutoNumber</type>
</fields>
```

When I manually set this to true my Force IDE reports an error:

```
Deprecation not supported in this organization
```

Does this mean I could have an org with this feature enabled?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is indeed a tease, and gives the impression it can be enabled. Sadly it is for future use as far as I am currently aware and cannot be enabled.

Comment: Are you working for Salesforce and know this for sure?

Comment: No, I do not work for Salesforce and do not know this for sure. As far as I am aware as an ISV that has asked about this recently (last 6 months) it is not currently available.

Comment: Thank Andrew. I opened a Case for this and got the same reply, but I just hoped to get some secret insights from Salesforce PMs here ;-)

Comment: I actually talked to the product manager who was running the pilot for this in the past: they hit some critical issues and aborted the pilot program. It's on the roadmap (somewhere) but there's no way to do it currently.